# Add keywords to sites, for improved searching

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, ios-app

Some of the network sites have names like Seasoned Advice which don't inherently represent their content. I was trying to remember the name for the 'Cooking Stack Exchange' and couldn't find it by searching for `cooking`, `kitchen` or `food`.

I think this quickly becomes frustrating on mobile.

My suggestion is to add some keywords that aren't displayed but are indexed in addition to the name and description of each network site.

Some more examples:

- `linux` doesn't list the Ubuntu site
- `arcade` doesn't return the Arqade site
- `bike` doesn't return the Bicycles site

Comment: It must do this a little already. Searching 'Cooking' returns Seasoned Advice for me, and 'Gaming' returns Arqade, 'Cycling' for Bicycles etc.. but maybe it's restricted to 1 key word describing the action

Comment: They already added the search to include the subdomains, but it could be better indeed.

Comment: The tagline in the tour is _"Seasoned Advice is a site for professional and amateur cooks and chefs"_ @OGHaza... I suspect that's why cooking gets it. Though, strangely "cooks" doesn't.

Comment: The tagline in Seasoned Advice for me is "professional and amateur chefs", so it doesn't appear for search terms `cooks` or `cooking` on my iPhone.

Comment: The tagline in the search box doesn't show the "cooks and chefs", but searching for cooking does work on desktop (no idea why cooks wouldn't) - based on the searches that return 'Bicylces' (cycling, commute, repairs)  it does indeed seem to be matching against the tag line like @ben says.

Comment: @OGHaza I'm pretty sure it only searches the `name` and `audience` fields of the [data returned by the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=!SmNuW54g.*OkR9oETG&run=true). Again, searching for `cooking` [*DOES NOT* return any results on the iOS app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4nes23h9xo26xb/2014-02-13%2013.13.26.png).

Answer (score 4):

Yep, the bigger blacker bar is checking the site URL and we weren't.  Fixed in the next build.  That fixes Seasoned Advice.  The other stuff is a more general issue with the data available.  We're realistically not going to do more than the bar can do.

Fixed in the next build.